# View list of installed plugins in Cinema 4D

Tags: cinema4d, plugins

How do you view a list or in some way know that a plugin was loaded in Cinema 4D? A friend of mine sent me a plugin he made and wanted me to try it, but I can't tell if it's even loaded.

Not sure if this is the right place for this question.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is a `plugins` folder in your installation directory, all installed plugins are listed there.

Comment: @poor Thanks for the help! Actually I was wondering if there is a way to see in the application itself because sometimes I put plugins in the "plugins" directory and I don't notice anything different in C4D

Comment: I'd like to help, but this depends on the plugin and how it is written... If you know the name, search for a tutorial or the manual to find images and you'll see in which area/viewport its used.

Comment: Glad I could help :) Written an answer, just to have one, because our answer ratio needs work, see: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4/audio-video-production

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `plugins` folder in your **installation directory**. Whether you are on mac or a windows machine, all installed plugins are listed there.

Search for a tutorial, the manual or some images to identify in which area or viewport it's used.